# Codeigniter query returns false

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query that gets the schedule of a employee and display it in table. I sampled some employees with the default schedules but when I try to retrieve others that have different schedule, it always returns false meaning the table is empty. Here is the query that I made:

```
function get_Sked($id,$from,$to)
{
    $query = "SELECT c.dt, a.TimeFrom,a.TimeTo FROM schedule a LEFT JOIN cal c ON a.SkedDate = c.dt AND a.EmpID = ? WHERE c.dt BETWEEN DATE(?) AND DATE(?) GROUP BY c.dt ORDER BY c.dt ASC";

    $query = $this->db->query($query,array($id,$from,$to));

    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

and this is the method that calls it:

```
$data['sked'] = $this->DBmodel->get_Sked($id,$dFrom,$dTo);

    if($data['sked'] == false)
    {
        echo "Default Schedule of 8:00 am to 5:00 pm."; //if table is empty show default sched.

        var_dump($data['sked']);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($data['sked'] as $val) //this will show the content of the table.
```

I am using the same query sequence as the others and not having problems only this one.....

I change my query structure to this:

```
$this->db->select('c.dt,a.TimeFrom,a.TimeTo');
    $this->db->from('cal c');
    $this->db->join('schedule a','a.SkedDate = c.dt');
    $this->db->where('a.EmpID',$id);
    $this->db->where('c.dt',$from);
    $this->db->where('c.dt',$to);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

but returns false still....

Comment: I also echoed inside the function query the value of the three variables and it receives the values that I passed from controller to model... so the only error here is in the query...

Comment: I also tried the codeigniter format of join but same results it only returns false value....

Comment: I carefully segmented the query and it returns false every time I try to combine my calendar table to my schedule table...

Comment: i think echo query and then run it in your mysql database ..you will get the actual mistake in mysql

Comment: Sorry my mistake I accidentally deleted the cal table so it will not really produce any results because its empty... thank you for the views much appreciated.... mostly the one that post a comment....